# how to subtract value of grep result in bash scripting

Tags: bash

```
    #!/bin/bash

YESTERDAY=`TZ=GMT+48 date +%Y%m%d`
filename="import$YESTERDAY.log"
today=`date +%Y%m%d`
today="import$today.log"

value1=$(grep -i 'Invalid cells in file' "$filename" | cut -f2 -d':') // gives result 2458



value2=$(grep -i 'Invalid cells in file' "$today" | cut -f2 -d':') // gives result 1236

difference='$value1'-'$value2'
treshold=1000

if [[ $difference -gt $treshold ]]
then
```

I am tryng to subtract results of those grep's but it gives operator error which shown below

line 14: [[: $value1-$value2: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "$value1-$value2")

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use the `$((...))` notation, as you can see in this example:

```
Prompt>v1=2458
Prompt>v2=1236
Prompt>echo $((v1-v2))
Prompt>1222
```

So, for you it means the following:

```
difference=$((value1-value2))
```